# Как заставить Windows Phone 8.1 отображать сайт целиком?

Tags: вёрстка, windows-phone-8.1, meta

Требуется сделать так, чтобы на всех мобильных устройствах сайт отображался целиком (*шириной 1170*).
Для многих платформ помогло применение метатега

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1170px"/>
```

Но на платформе **Windows Phone (8.1)** сайт все равно отображается только частично (*в масштабе 100%*). Как заставить браузер **«ужать»** страницу, чтобы изначально она была видна целиком?

Comment: Проблему можно решить метатегом `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1170px, initial-scale=0.27, maximum-scale=0.27"/>`, но это очень плохое решение, т.к. ограничивает возможности пользователя масштабировать.

Comment: Не знаю, каким образом, но помогло сочетание в ссs: 
`@-ms-viewport { width: 1170px; }
@-webkit-viewport { width: 1170px; }
@-moz-viewport { width: 1170px; }
@-o-viewport { width: 1170px; }
@viewport { width: 1170px; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А так ?

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1170px, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Нет, к сожалению, так не срабатывает.

Comment: А вотт такой CSS ?:

@-ms-viewport {
  width: 1170px;
  }

Comment: Тоже нет. И хак с JS пробовала - не помогает. (может, дело в том, что везде стараются сделать наоборот - сразу показывать увеличенную часть страницы?! и поэтому методы оттуда не работают)

Comment: Не знаю, как, но css, похожий на предложенный @bim решил вопрос. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, красивого решения не нашлось, и пришлось изощряться следующим образом:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1170px"/>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/)) {
        $('meta[name="viewport"]').attr('content', 'width=1170px, minimum-scale=1');
        var wndW = $(window).width();
        var docW = $(document).width();
        $("html").css({transform: "scale(" + wndW/docW + ")", transformOrigin: "0 0" });
    }
</script>
```

Если кто-нибудь предложит более изящное решение, то буду очень рада!